# Boundedness of solutions to Hill's equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$-u''+qu = 0$ has the form
$U' = AU$, where the diagonal entries of $A$ are zero.
Where $q$ is $\omega$-periodic

Now the Wronskian of the $0$-cannonical fundamental matrix is given by

$$W(x) =W(0)\exp(\int^{x}_{0}tr A) = 1 \times 1  = 1$$

and the eigenvalues $\mu_1,\mu_2$of the monodromy,$\Phi(\omega)$, matrix satisfy

$tr\Phi(\omega) =\mu_1+\mu_2, \det\Phi(\omega) = \mu_1 \mu_2 $.

Now I am given that one of the eigenvalues $\mu > 1$, then the other eigenvalue $\mu' < 1$, this would mean that one of the Floquet solutions has an increasing envelope and the other decreasing. The Wronskian is non-zero so we have linear independence. Hence $u,u'$ form a fundamental matrix....

I am trying to conclude that all non trivial solutions are unbounded. But can not quite make the jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am referring to the section on Hill's equation in page 207 of [Chicone's Ordinary Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387307699) book.

Because $\lambda<1$, the fundamental set of solutions of the equation is of the form $e^{\lambda t}p_1(t)$ and $e^{-\lambda t}p_2(t)$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are $\omega-$periodic.